# Expression: Be the poorer for something

Tags: expressions

What can constitute a dictionary entry for "be the poorer for something"? I know what it means but I can't find any dictionaries contain it so to explain it to someone else. I found it very peculiar that there was no online source about that expression.

Comment: Why does the phrase need a dictionary entry, when it means the sum of its constituent parts? We know what "To be" means, we know what "poorer" means.

Comment: @slim I don't say that it needs I say what a possible entry could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly difficult without re-using the words "to be" or "poor".

> *To be the poorer for (something)*: To be more poor as a result of (something).

Since the most appropriate of the Chambers definitions of "poor" is "in a sorry condition".

> *To be the poorer for (something)*: To be in a more sorry condition as a result of (something)

But I question the need for this, as the definition is tautological. Its full meaning is in the words used.

Comment: Yes that was my problem too as I couldn't find different words to express it. Thanks though for the try, it is useful.